# Pyenv BUILD FAILED while Integrate Spark (Scala) and Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, scala, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
pyenv build fails. Trying to integrate spark scala with jupyter notbook as described here[enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/datlife/9d36a2832b358e81daf1d3f6bcb768af)

```
➜  ~ pyenv install 3.8.2 
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.8.2.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.2/Python-3.8.2.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.8.2...
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk
^D
BUILD FAILED (OS X 11.2.1 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/_v/qvsxvlw51rxb43z929hyv45w0000gn/T/python-build.20210222233923.72853
Results logged to /var/folders/_v/qvsxvlw51rxb43z929hyv45w0000gn/T/python-build.20210222233923.72853.log

Last 10 log lines:
extern int _NSGetExecutablePath(char* buf, uint32_t* bufsize)                 __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_2, __IPHONE_2_0);
                                                     ^
clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include   -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include   -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror=implicit-function-declaration  -I./Include/internal  -I. -I./Include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/Users/quais/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/include  -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/Users/quais/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE_BUILTIN  -DPy_BUILD_CORE_BUILTIN -I./Include/internal -c ./Modules/posixmodule.c -o Modules/posixmodule.o
./Modules/posixmodule.c:9197:15: error: implicit declaration of function 'sendfile' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        ret = sendfile(in, out, offset, &sbytes, &sf, flags);
              ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [Modules/posixmodule.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
1 warning generated.
➜  ~ 
Saving session...completed.
Deleting expired sessions...none found.

[Process completed]
```

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this by getting an older version the environment. Apparently the latest version is not supported even if i have the 12+ version of Xcode

```
pyenv install 3.7.9
```